# Invalid application's package name "com.DemoProject" in 'AndroidManifest.xml' in React native

Tags: react-native

While installing the app I am getting a warning 'Invalid application's package name "com.DemoProject" in AndroidManifest.xml'
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rename package name from "com.DemoProject"  to "com.app.DemoProject".